# Is it possible to use boost::mpl::contains on a static vector_c?

Tags: c++, compile-time, static-assert

I am searching for a less klunky answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696326/how-can-the-allowed-range-of-an-integer-be-restricted-with-compile-time-errors), namely check at compile time whether a template parameter is in a list of numbers.  I would like to not just check the range of a function, but check whether the integer is in an arbitrary list of integers at compile time.  The author of that answer wrote that "Things will be much easier when C++0x is out with constexpr, static_assert and user defined literals," but I don't see *exactly* how.

I thought to use [this boost::mpl::contains](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/contains.html) function (or whatever it's called), but it only takes a type as a second parameter.

Comment: `vector_c` will hold types as well. Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What does that question have to do with the question of whether or not you can `contains` on a `vector_c`? Is the question just: how do you use `contains` on such a sequence?

Comment: Sorry for the poor choice of words.  What I want to do is check at compile time whether a template parameter is in a list of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the fun of it:

```
template <int first, int... last>
struct int_list {
    static bool constexpr check(int c) {
      return first == c ? true : int_list<last...>::check(c);
    }
};

template <int first>
struct int_list<first> {
    static bool constexpr check(int c) { return c == first; }
};

using my_sequence = int_list<1, 5, 12, 45, 76, 60>;

static_assert(my_sequence::check(10), "No tenner");
```

Comment: @user4581301, albeit different ones :)