# Creating a digit Datatype with restriction, an int between -10 and 10

Tags: c++, types

I really need a new datatype in my application, which will only store numbers from -10 to 10. Is there a way to create a datatype with specific values, which will raise an error if the value is invalid? I used:

```
typedef int digit;
```

The thing that happens is a new datatype which is actually int is created.
I also tried this:

```
typedef int{-10 > int value < 10} digit;
```

but it raised this:

```
exit status 1
main.cpp:3:12: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
typedef int{-10 > int value < 10} digit;
           ^
main.cpp:3:35: error: 'digit' does not name a type; did you mean 'div_t'?
typedef int{-10 > int value < 10} digit;
                                    ^~~~~
                                  div_t
```

Comment: C++ is not ADA. It's not possible with fundamental types.. You can write a class to handle the datatype. You can overload most operators, thus handle overflows in custom ways.

Comment: is there another way'

Comment: Hi @Kamil please use the answer section for answers thanks

Comment: It could be a nice feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not have such a feature. It would be quite nice in certain situations, but non-trivial to provide in the language (and inefficient to use, to some degree).

You can create a class that wraps `int` and does its own bounds checking (or however you want the type to behave). You would then have to wrap all the arithmetic operations too. Not too onerous, but a bit of a pain in the neck. And, again, not efficient (every single arithmetic operation will need a branch!).

Generally we just use an `int` and do our checks in our code logic when needed, at a higher level. I can't make specific suggestions without knowing your use case.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3696326/560648) that does half of it.

Comment: Thanks, that works

Comment: @AndriiChumakov It doesn't do everything you seem to want; it only validates the initial value

Comment: I understand, that I will be able to attach a new value with a bigger number like 11, because this code checks the value of a number only before the assignment.

Comment: @AndriiChumakov Not quite - the only way to obtain the value is, well, by value, and involves a conversion back to `int`, so the range-checked type is effectively immutable. Converting it back to that type you'd get another range check. This may or may not be suitable for your purposes.

Comment: ok, I will check if it will be useful

Comment: @AndriiChumakov Good luck!

Comment: Found another duplicate with more possible solutions - you should have plenty of options now.

Comment: @Useless That's pretty good, nice work. ("Found" seems like an overstatement since you wrote the best answer there :P)

Comment: "Found somewhere in the back of my mind," perhaps :)